# how to remove this error "*sys-package-mgr* " and how to run python file into following case :

Tags: java, python, jython-2.5

i have a scenario such as below:

1. pyhton file name is sir_desc.py placed into this path "E:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/sir_desc.py"
2. jython-2.5 jar file placed into ext folder of java dierectory
3. i able to run python code by using these command from commandprompt :

   C:\Python27>python

   > > > import sir_desc
   > > >       sir_desc.get_url_text("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/")
4. [steps to run python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsk4m.jpg)
5. python code run successfully and return text as output

how to run python file from following java code and how i remove  "*sys-package-mgr* : can't create package cashe dir" ??

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class method {

public static void main(String[] args) {

PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile("E:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_92/bin/sir_desc.py");
PyObject str = interpreter.eval("repr(get_url_text(\"http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/\"))");
System.out.println(str.toString());

}
}
```